# Is there a way to add a tab between characters in a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I've created an app that templates a letter and would like to get the CC values at the bottom to line up properly. The attached image shows that the foo line is not quite a full character off of the bar line.

[image]

The foo line was done using:

`paragrapgh.insertHtml('<div>CC:&emsp;&emsp;foo</div>');`

The bar line is it's own paragraph so I was able to get proper tab spacing using: 
`secondParagraph.leftIndent = 36;`

Is there a way to set a proper tab indent between characters using office.js? From what I've seen in the documentation `leftIndent` seems like the only option but that will only work on the paragraph itself, not in-between the text.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Update:**

I've tried this:

`paragrapgh.insertHtml('<div>CC:\tfoo</div>');`

Word treats `\t` as a single space not a tab unfortunately.

Comment: Don't use insertHTML, use `insertText` - see my Answer. This is why Word Online doesn't support tabs. HTML doesn't support tabs (excessive white space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Office JS code (from Script Lab) works for me on the desktop. It uses standard, minimal Word Open XML to insert (in place of the current selection) a paragraph with a left-aligned tab-stop. It then writes text to the document, with tab characters to align the text.

Note that, since Word On-line does not support tab stops and tab characters, this will run in Word On-line, but the effect will be different (no alignment).

```
//create paragraph with tab stops and tabs
async function run() {
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
        let sXml = '<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"><pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:body><w:p><w:pPr><w:tabs><w:tab w:val="left" w:pos ="851"/></w:tabs></w:pPr><w:r><w:t></w:t></w:r></w:p></w:body></w:document></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part></pkg:package>';

        //console.log("XML: " + sXml);
        let para = context.document.getSelection();
        para.insertOoxml(sXml, "Replace");
        para.insertText("CC:\tPerson1\n\tPerson2", "Start");
        await context.sync();
    });
}
```

The result looks like this

[image]

The relevant part of the Word Open XML for a paragraph with tab stops:

```
<w:body>
<w:p><w:pPr><w:tabs><w:tab w:val="left" w:pos ="851"/></w:tabs></w:pPr><w:r><w:t></w:t></w:r></w:p>
</w:body>
```

Answer (score -1):

use escape characters (in this case: '\t')

```js
context.document.body.insertParagraph("check out how to tab next word: Hell\to tab!", "end");
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to define a tab stop? Just inserting ANSI 9 doesn't guarantee that the text will line up, depending on the length of what's on the left (CC, in this case).

Comment: i dont know, why dont we wait for clarification before voting down :)

Comment: Thanks for the response but word treats `\t` as a space not a tab.

Comment: @Alfree92 Which platform are you looking the result on? Windows desktop, Word On-line, MacWord...?

Comment: @Alfree92 I'm now looking at Word Online and it appears to not support tabs. I'm not able to insert tabs by pressing the Tab key, nor can I see any tabs if I open a document edited in a desktop version that contains tabs. And if I open a document on the desktop where (supposedly) a tab has been inserted by the proposed code (we see a space) there's not even a space! So if you need to see the alignment you ask about on-line, I think you'll need to use a two-column table: CC in the left column, top row; the other text in the second column.

Comment: @CindyMeister Our target is the desktop version. I was hoping to avoid using a table but it seems like I  might have to. Thanks!

Comment: @Alfree92 The approach Juan Balmori suggested does work for me in Word 2016 on Windows desktop. For what you want: `range.insertText("CC:\tPerson1\n\tPerson2", "End");` - But as I remarked to Juan, you can't be sure the alignment is going to be correct simply relying on the default tab stops (1.27 cm).